# What is best practice for coding an email contact button on your site

Tags: javascript, html, email, href, mailto

I don't want to use mailto: because I personally find it annoying when it opens outlook which I never use.

```
<a href="mailto:homer@example.com">Email Homer</a>
```

Should I have the button open a new page with just the email address in it? Is there a way to have it automatically copy?

Comment: It doesn't open Outlook explicitly, it opens whatever the user has defined as their default mail application. if you don't use Outlook, then change your default to whatever you use.

Comment: Well [set your browser](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/06/set-gmail-as-default-email-client-in.html) up to not use outlook! It can only use what it is told to do.

Comment: epascarello: most people don't know how. The OP is trying to make it easier for the user.

Comment: I don't want to make your question sound invalid, but just because you find it annoying (as do I), doesn't mean that others don't find it useful. This has been how it's done for a while now, so it may be an annoyance for this functionality to go away. I would suggest following Diodeus's method or creating your own form that will email the intended recipient.

Comment: Concerning the copy option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options basically.  Use mailto which will use the user's defined email application (could be outlook, yahoo, gmail, whatever).  This is the fastest to program since you don't do a thing, just add the link and be done.
The other is to create your own email page. The cons to this is that it's more work from you. The pros is that you can specify more fields that give you more info (for example, order #, phone, etc). This would use your email server though, not the client's, so make sure the client adds his email address in the form as mandatory (and maybe verification too)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also give the user a choice to simply copy/paste:

```
<a href="mailto:homer@example.com">Email Homer</a> (homer@example.com)
```

Comment: Messing with copying is not worth your time.. I usually just put the email address as the text so you can copy it if you prefer. You could write a form that your server can then email but seems like a waste of time to me. So I agree with Diodeus, just copy and paste..

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the contact button is an envelope icon and I'm trying to avoid cluttering the design with a long email address.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separated web page (like Contact us) where I'd place a contact form (sender's name, email, subject and message). At this page you could also publish your email address with a link/button ["Copy to clipboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).